# Using re.match() to find a string starting with two possible letters

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I'm using re to parse content from a scientific software. My code works fine and the strings I'm interested are in the form "**s a_number**". Here is a snip of the code so far:

```
d2_s_lines = re.match(r"s\s\d(.*)", dd2_valid_lines)
```

But the new version of the software is, now, producing also strings in the form "**k a_number**".

So, my question is: is there a way to tell re.match() that I'm looking for strings starting with **s** OR **k** so it can find "**k a_number**" and "**s a_number**"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, you can group them together with brackets `[sk]`

Comment: you can also use a pipe `|` to "or" together characters, e.g. a|b|c would match either a, b, or c.

Comment: Thank you so much, guys.

Answer (score 1):

Specify a set of characters instead of a single character.

```
/[sk].../
```